# Compile different files for device/simulator in XCode

Tags: ios, xcode, build, compilation, simulator

I'm including a 3rd party library (sources) with my static library. It it intended for device only (since it includes some ARM assembly routines) and I do not wish to build it for the simulator (I just want my app to compile there so I can test the GUI).

- Creating another target for simulator only is not an option since my projects reference my library as a dependency and it would be a nightmare to maintain.
- Adding #if (TARGET_OS_IPHONE) for those files is not an option as well since these are not my original sources and I would like to update them easily for updates (there are more than 200 files there and I do not with to modify all of them)

I'm looking for a way (similar to #if (TARGET_OS_IPHONE) in source files) which will work from the IDE itself (so I can exclude a file from the actual build process based on my target architecture). The only thing I found is an option to exclude/include a file from a target - but not for a specific architecture.

Is there a way to set architecture conditions per specific files?

Comment: What language has the library's interface, Obj-C, C++ or plain C? And how many methods contains the interface?

Comment: I actually have several libraries, most in C++ and few in Obj-C. They all not required for simulator (they all involve audio/video processing), but I at least want the project to build properly on the simulator since it's faster to test the UI there.

Comment: Sounds like there is no easy solution. If possible, try to separate all calls to library in one or more facades that are created by abstract factories depending on the target. Then use mock objects for x86 code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet would be to separate the third party library into a new target that builds it as a static framework. Set it as a dependency for your project, and then set the static framework to be conditionally linked as described by Apple here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/ios_development_workflow/115-Configuring_Applications/configuring_applications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007959-CH19-SW7

You can add a new target by selecting the Project in the project navigator and then hitting the Add Target button at the bottom of the Editor pane. You can setup a cocoa touch static library and then assign the relevant .m or .c files to belong only to that target. Then select your app's target and add the static framework in the "Target Dependencies" section of the Build Phases tab.

Answer (score 0):

You can conditionally include/exclude files in Xcode using `EXCLUDED_SOURCE_FILE_NAMES` based on sdk. For example:

```
EXCLUDED_SOURCE_FILE_NAMES[sdk=*simulator*] = something.cpp something_else.cpp
```

See [Conditional Compilation](https://davedelong.com/blog/2018/07/25/conditional-compilation-in-swift-part-2/) article for more details